# Calculating Field based on Domain Description of Another Field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vbscript, vb

I am trying to get the description from a field to write to another field.
However, When I calculate the new field it gives me the code and not the description. I tried using VB, but I can't seem to get the code correct. 
1 = Buildings
2 = Roads
3 = Other Paved

```
If [ClassName] = "1" then
x = "Buildings"

Elif [ClassName] = "2" then
x = "Roads"

Else
x = "Other Paved"
End If
```

Can anyone advise?

Comment: You need to add a screen shot of the calculate tool so we can see if you are using it correctly, Also is the field `ClassName` of type string when it is holding values 1,2 or 3?

Comment: Hello, I managed to fix my problem. I ended up just exporting my domains as a table and then joined them back in with my initial table by code number. Then I had both the code and the description in one place.